# Can you say "a project is on par with schedule"?

Tags: idioms

Is it idiomatic to say

> The project is on par with the schedule

? Or does "or par" mean "up to the standard", so you need to say

> The project is in line with the schedule

?

Comment: The project is **on schedule**.

Comment: Or "The project is going according to schedule." That exact sentence is used here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20according%20to%20schedule

Comment: In British English [we nearly always include the indefinite article:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+par+with%2Con+a+par+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) *X is on **a** par with Y*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this isn’t correct. The problem is that “on par with” roughly means “comparable to.” You can’t say the project is comparable to a schedule, because the project itself is not a schedule, nor is it similar to a schedule.

You could say “the project is on schedule” or “roughly on schedule.” If you really wanted to use “on par with,” you would have to say something like, “Progress on the project is on par with expectations” - but this is needlessly wordy.